# JQuery append error when appending ampersand data

Tags: jquery, append

I'm using firefox 14.0.1 and the latest jquery.
The following code errors in my application, because of the unescaped ampersand. So far so good.
However, when I copy the page source to a file and make my web server serve that, the code works fine.
Any ideas what is happening here?!

Warmly

John

```
function create_dialog () {

    var new_dialog = $('<div id="new_dialog"/>');

    new_dialog.dialog({ autoOpen: true, modal: true, open: foo, height: 400 });

    function foo() {

        $.ajax({
           url:      'http://localhost:8010/ecomm/?ajax=1&state=pop_pl_cst',
           cache:    false,
           success:  function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                         { new_dialog.append('<div>' + 'foo A&E' + '</div>'); },
           dataType: 'xml',
           error:    function(jqXHR, textStatus, fred ) {alert('oops ' + textStatus);},
        });

    }; // foo

}
```

EDIT:
The above is a simple version of my code, to reproduce the error. The below is the actual version. While I can escape the ampersand, etc, it doesn't explain why the same code works differently from what appears to be the same page. There must be something different somewhere...

```
function create_dialog ( ) {

    var new_dialog = $('<div id="new_dialog"/>');

    new_dialog.dialog({ autoOpen: true, modal: true, open: foo, height: 400 });

    function foo() {

        $.ajax({
            url:      'http://localhost:8010/ecomm/?ajax=1&state=pop_pl_cst',
            cache:    false,
            success:  success,
            dataType: 'xml',
            error:    function(jqXHR, textStatus, fred ) {alert('oops ' + textStatus);},
        });

        function success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

//             alert(data);
            $(data).find('row').each(process_row);
            function process_row () {
                console.log($(this).attr('pop_text'));
                new_dialog.append($('<div>' + $(this).attr('pop_text') + '</div>'));
//                 new_dialog.append('<div>' + 'foo' + '</div>');
            }

        } // success

    }; // foo

}
```

One thing I have noticed is that when the datatype is text, jquery parses it to xml in my standalone page (the one that works) but doesn't in the app page.

Comment: The error is: SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified  

div.innerHTML = wrap[1] + elem + wrap[2];

Comment: Can you post the code, which fires the error, or which has that `wrap[1]`

Comment: The wrap is from jquery.js. line 6325.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is pretty forgiving; it won't drop everything when it encounters a problem. But just because it works when you feed it bad code from the server, it doesn't mean it's right.

Unescaped entities cause problems, just like the one you're experiencing. *That's why you need to escape them*. So follow the rules, escape your HTML, and you'll be good to go.

[mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js#L53) has a pretty neat example:

```
var entityMap = {
  "&": "&amp;",
  "<": "&lt;",
  ">": "&gt;",
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#39;',
  "/": '&#x2F;'
};

function escapeHtml(string) {
  return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
    return entityMap[s];
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there a function to escape text? I don't seem able to find it. I'm new to js and to jquery.

Comment: Edited answer with an example

Comment: Thanks for that. Trouble is, that doesn't explain why it works on one page but not on another (seemingly identical) page with exactly the same data!

Comment: The problem is as I mentioned, HTML isn't strict. Sometimes it will let bad things slide (unescaped characters, no ending tags etc). But you can't *ever* assume something will work if you don't follow the spec. The spec is there to ensure that it behaves properly 100% of the time. And the spec says you need to encode ampersands.

Comment: It's XHTML, strict. The innerHTML is escaping in one case but not the other. All very strange. fwiw, when I do the replace, it works in both cases. I need to find out what causes innerHTML to escape the string...

Comment: That wasn't what I meant by strict (I picked the wrong word). XHTML will still render fine even if you don't follow the rules, that's my point. It doesn't "enforce" anything by means of blocking rendering if it detects a problem, so it's very lenient.

Comment: Absolutely. But if I pass a string to innerHTML on one page and pass the *same* string on another page I expect the same result. This isn't the case.

Comment: The error is from:
div.innerHTML = wrap[1] + elem + wrap[2];
on line 6325 of jquery.js (I'm using the latest version).

Both pages get the same xml. When I put an alert before the above code and replace ampersand with XXX, both alerts show the same string.

Comment: I found out what the problem is. If the mime-type of the page is application/xhtml+xml, the string is not escaped automatically. The app page was this type, the standalone page is text/html. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

#### Then escape it:

```
new_dialog.append('<div>' + 'foo A&amp;E' + '</div>');
```